# How to use base tag conditionally?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, relative-path, absolute-path

I've a angular app. Which is going to deployed in two site (same code).
I'm using the following base tag for site A

```
<base href="https://A.com/">
```

But for second site I need

```
<base href="https://B.com/">
```

As the repo is same, is there any way to achieve this?

I've tried using

```
<base href="/">
```

But this is causing issue when reloading the app in nested state 
i.e. If the url is https://A.com/x/y/z
It's causing issues, and trying to get resources from /x/y/z path. But I need to get the resources always from root.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks is advance..

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<base href="{{(siteName == 'site A')?'https://A.com/':'https://B.com/'}}">
```

Comment: is this angular code right? I mean the siteName variable, If it's angular, The app is also being loaded after the html document... Can you please let me know?